# translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is true for Interface Builder View

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, xcode7

I've seen in several places now that views in Interface Builder should have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to false by default. From the [UIView doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints):

> By default, the property is set to YES for any view you programmatically create. If you add views in Interface Builder, the system automatically sets this property to NO.

And yet in my view controller, this assertion fails:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    assert(self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints == false)
}
```

In the Interface Builder Document I have `Use Auto Layout` checked. Why is `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` true?

XCode 7.3

Comment: `If you add views in Interface Builder, the system automatically sets this property to NO.` In case of Uiviewcontroller.view you didn't add it to IB, it's added when you add a view controller, maybe `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`is only set to 0 to uiview you add in a parent view.

Comment: What I'm saying is that your case you didn't add self.view to IB, but a view controller that generate a view for you, If you add subviews in IB to your view does they also avec `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`set to false ?

Comment: Same issue Xcode 9.1